# sprintf formatting of double value

Tags: c++, c, unix, printf

I have one specific problem while converting `double` values to string using `sprintf()` in UNIX.

For example I have two values:

```
double a = 0.009984354523452;
double b = 0.01;
```

While converting, I am using:

```
sprintf(somestringvar, "Double value : %.15f \n", a);
sprintf(diffstringvar, "Double value : %.15f \n", b);
```

to convert to a string.

My problem is for the 'a', the value is printing properly but for the value of 'b', 0's are appended at the tail end. Please provide me any common way to represent 'a' and 'b' as exact values.

Comment: I would use std::ostringstream for this kind of thing.

Comment: And in general, don't use `sprintf()`, as it can lead to buffer overruns. Use `snprintf()` instead, or one of the `_s` "safe" versions Microsoft provides on Windows. p.s. Welcome to Stack Overflow!

Comment: Hi thanks for early responses. ostringstream is not taking entire precision. a value is printing as 0.009976 only. I can use snprintf() but the problem is while printing values properly.

Comment: Another thing you have to be aware of: In general, floating point numbers *cannot* be represented *exactly* because the mantissa has only a finite length. E.g. `printf("1/10 = %.50f\n", 0.1);` outputs the following on my machine: `d = 0.10000000000000000555111512312578270211815834045410`. You might want to read up on the [floating point representation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point).

Comment: It was valuable information. Its true that the floating point numbers cannot be represented exactly but am just trying to print the values whatever are there in particular double variable. Am actually accessing data from database, in this case i have to print to user exactly that whatever is there in database. But not by "normalizing" or "truncating" or by "appending zeroes at tail". By using %g or %f or ostringstream  the values are being normalized and truncated (like 0.009984354523452 as 0.009984) if i use %.20f big values are fine but small ones like 0.01 as 0.0100..... with 18 zeroes

Comment: @user1357856 If it's stored in the database as a string, maybe you should use a string. Or do you need to do calculations with them?

Comment: Yes we need to provide that funtionality to user. While accessing as string am able to obtain exact values. For displaying accessing as string and for operations accessing as a double is not suggestable.

Comment: Based on the vote count, people seem to like my answer. If you found it valuable, you should click the checkmark near its vote count to accept it. That's how things typically work on Stack Overflow, and it encourages people to answer more of your questions in the future. Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You get zeros when printing b because you told printf to print 15 decimal places (`%.15f`), and it is obediently doing so. To get something "exact", you might have better luck with simple `%g`.

---

[Update based on recent comments]

Things really depend on what you mean by "exact". If by exact, you mean "what the user originally entered", then a double might not be the best choice for you. Perhaps storing the value as a string and then converting it to a double when you need to use it in a computation might work. Once a text-based decimal number is converted to a double, it generally is no longer exactly the same as the text. While `printf()` or `ostream` will dutifully print exactly what the double holds (and sometimes it gets lucky and what it prints looks the same as the original value), the problem is that the double itself no longer holds the actual original value. And in fact it never did.

Alternatively, you might favor a precise numeric implementation rather than something inherently approximate like doubles. For example, MySQL has [NUMERIC and DECIMAL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fixed-point-types.html) types that support perfect precision at the cost of forcing you to specify the number of integer and decimal places ahead of time. This is called [arbitrary precision arithmetic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arbitrary-precision_arithmetic) and there are libraries for doing this in C/C++.

Comment: Thanks for reply i can understand logical part for addition of zeoes. But the problem is in runtime i should read values from database. Values can be of any type as above shown, so am looking for general way of printing exact values. I tried '%g' even it is normalizing value 'a' to 0.009976

Comment: Why do people keep voting this down? If there's a problem with it, speak up so I can improve it or provide an alternate answer of your own.